# Use elementary set operations to show sequence of sets is disjoint

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an arbitrary sequence of sets. Construct from it a new sequence $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined by $B_1=A_1$ and for $n>1$, we let $B_n=A_n\smallsetminus \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k\right)$. I want to show the $B_n$ are pairwise disjoint. That is, for any $i \ne j$, without loss of generality $i>j$,
\begin{align*}
B_i\cap B_j
&=\left(A_i \smallsetminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{i-1} A_n\right)\cap \left(A_j\smallsetminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n\right) \\
&=\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{i-1}(A_i \smallsetminus A_n)\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1}(A_j\smallsetminus A_n)\right) \\
&=\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1} \left((A_i \smallsetminus A_n) \cup (A_j \smallsetminus A_n)\right) \cap \bigcap_{n=j}^{i-1} (A_i \smallsetminus A_n) \\
&=\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1} \left((A_i \cup A_j) \smallsetminus A_n\right) \cap \bigcap_{n=j}^{i-1} (A_i \smallsetminus A_n) \\
&=\cdots \\
&=\emptyset
\end{align*}
It's easy enough to argue in words that this intersection must equal the empty set:

> For any $x$ in $\left(A_i \smallsetminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{i-1} A_n\right)\cap \left(A_j\smallsetminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n\right)$, we would have $x \in A_i$ and $x
>  \in A_j$, but $x \notin \bigcup_{n=1}^{i=1} A_n$ and $x \notin
>  \bigcup_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n$, i.e.  $x \notin A_n$, $n=1,\ldots,i-1$ and
>    $x \notin A_n$, $n=1,\ldots,j-1$. Since $i>j$, the last statement is
>    redundant. Thus $x \in A_i$ and $x \in A_j$, but $x \notin A_n$,
>    $i=1,\ldots,i-1$. But since $j<i$, the statement $i=1,\ldots,i-1$
>    implies $x \notin A_j$, which is a contradiction.

However I don't want to prove this in a paragraph of words -- I want to show *algebraically* that the intersection must equal the empty set using basic set operations (properties of the set difference, unions and intersections, etc.) to manipulate the above equations. But I get stuck along the way and it's not obvious what rules I should use next to manipulate the above equations. Anyone see any neat tricks to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is proved like:
\begin{align}
B_i\cap B_j
&=\left(A_i -\bigcup_{n=1}^{i-1} A_n\right)\cap \left(A_j-\bigcup_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n\right) 
\\
&=\left(A_i \cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{i-1}A_n^c\right) \cap \left(A_j\cap\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n^c\right)
\\
&=\left(A_i \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{i-1}A_n^c\right)\cap A_j\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n^c\right)\tag1
\\
&=\left(A_i \cap \left(\left(\bigcap_{n=1, n\ne j}^{i-1}A_n^c\right)\cap A_j^c\right)\cap A_j\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n^c\right)\tag2
\\
&=\left(A_i \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1, n\ne j}^{i-1}A_n^c\right)\cap (A_j^c\cap A_j)\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n^c\right)\tag3
\\
&=\left(A_i \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1, n\ne j}^{i-1}A_n^c\right)\cap \varnothing\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n^c\right)
\\
&=\left(A_i \cap \varnothing\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n^c\right)
\\
&= \varnothing \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{j-1} A_n^c\right)
\\
&=\varnothing 
\end{align}
$(1)$ is because intersection is associative.

$(2):$  $A_j^c$ can be moved out of $\bigcap_{n=1}^{i-1}A_n^c$ because intersection is commutative and associative, as well as $i>j$.

$(3)$ is because intersection is associative.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $i>j$ then
$$B_j=A_j\mathbin\backslash\bigcup_{k=1}^{j-1}A_k
  =A_j\cap A_{j-1}^c\cap A_{j-2}^c\cap\cdots\cap A_1^c$$
and similarly
$$B_i=A_i\cap A_{i-1}^c\cap A_{i-2}^c\cap\cdots\cap A_j^c\cap\cdots\cap A_1^c\ .$$
By commutativity and associativity of intersection,
$$\eqalign{B_i\cap B_j
  &=A_i\cap A_{i-1}^c\cap A_{i-2}^c\cap\cdots\cap (A_j\cap A_j^c)\cap
    \cdots\cap (A_1^c\cap A_1^c)\cr
  &=\cdots\cap\varnothing\cap\cdots\cr
  &=\varnothing\ .\cr}$$